# controlling looping in d3.js

Tags: loops, d3.js

I am trying to control the iteration in inline function(d,i). For some specific cases I don't want i to increment, but the function should return something unrelated to the looping. In the next iteration, loop should start over from where it left without increment. The code snippet below prints out linear values of i, even though i is decremented in case where d.y_axis!=260

```
svgContainer.append("g").selectAll(".stringLabels").data(jsonCirclesJoined).enter().append("text").attr("class","stringLabels")
    .attr("x", function(d){return d.x_axis-2})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.y_axis})
    .text(function(d,i){ console.log(i); if (d.y_axis==260) {return d.label;} else { i--; return peers[focusedStudent][i+1]; }})
```

Comment: The "loop" is done externally and you can't change the counter like this. What are you actually trying to do? It sounds like you'd want to make your conditions part of the data.

Comment: `i` is a parameter to the function, not a global variable

Comment: The value that gets returned depends on a condition. If <condition==true>  value from array1 gets returned. If <condition==false> value from array2 gets returned. The only hack I can think of is to insert elements in array2 with dummy values at places where <condition==true> gets triggered.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by incrementing a counter whenever condition was true and accessing (i-counter)th element in false condition.